# Implicit function theorem for L^p?

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces, implicit-function-theorem

I am studying Ivar Ekeland's book and in one of the Lemma he uses the implicit function theorem on the map
\begin{eqnarray}
R\times R \times S &\to& L^2(0,T; C^{2n}) 
\end{eqnarray}
where $S$ is the unity sphere in $L^2(0,T; C^{2n})$.

My problem is that the only version I know for the implicit function theorem is for $R^k$ and manifolds.

So, he is thinking of $L^2(0,T; C^{2n})$ as a manifold? Or exist a version of the theorem to $L^p$ spaces?

Answer (score 4):

Banach spaces seem to be the relevant objects here. There is a version of the IFT for Banach spaces. See e.g. [this](http://www.math.ucsd.edu/~bdriver/231-02-03/Lecture_Notes/chap22.pdf) (warning: pdf!)

The relevant stuff start on page $12$.